# ASP.Net Range Validator Date stops working correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I am working in an ASP.Net Web Forms application and getting an error on a range validation control for a date.  Nothing has changed in this control and the min/max dates are set as properties.  The error is:

*The value '12/31/2199' of the MaximumValue property of 'rvWorkBlockFromDate' cannot be converted to type 'Date'.*

I know that this can be fixed by changing the min/max values to a culture neutral format, eg "yyyy/mm/dd".  However, this is a large application and I don't want to find every control and change the format of the min/max dates.

The other strange thing is that this does NOT occur for anyone else in my dev group.  They are using Windows 7 Pro and I am using Windows 10 Pro, but otherwise we are all in the same culture "en-US" and use the same tools and same version of VS 2013 Pro.

Any ideas why this would stop working for me?

Comment: Just want to confirm one thing, did you use same culture "en-US"? Also can you please check your machine's regional settings from control panel and check date format?

Comment: My culture setting was correct (“en-US”), but something changed my date formats and that was throwing off the conversion.  I did the reset and now the date conversions in RS are working again.

I am still not sure what would have changed these, but now I know where to fix it.

I went to Region in the Control Panel, Additional Settings, and clicked Reset.
This was driving me crazy; so, I wanted to share.
Please write this up as an answer and I will select it.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go to control panel >> region >> Additional Setting and click on reset to reset your settings.